# Rotating web-style and graphic layer

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I want to rotate my car symbol based on gps heading field from custom rest service.

I have attached my code:

```
$.get( "/gps/track/latest", function( data ) {
        $.each(data , function(index, val) { 
          const point = { //Create a point
            type: "point",
            longitude: val['lng'],
            latitude: val['lat']
          };

          let symbol = {
            type: "web-style",  // autocasts as new PictureMarkerSymbol()
            name: "BMW_3-Series",
            styleName: "EsriRealisticTransportationStyle",
          };

          const pointGraphic = new Graphic({
              geometry: point,
              symbol: symbol
          });
          carsLayer.add(pointGraphic);
        });
      });
```

How to use heading field data like following:

```
              visualVariables: [
                {
                  type: "rotation",
                  valueExpression: val['heading']
                }
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `rotation` visual variable of a renderer to achieve what you want. Take a look at the example I made for you,

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>
        Rotate Web Style Symbol
    </title>

    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #viewDiv {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.26/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.26/"></script>
    <script src="https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/satellites-3d/live/satellite.js"></script>

    <script>
        require([
            "esri/Map",
            "esri/views/MapView",
            "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
            "esri/Graphic",
            "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer"
        ], (Map, MapView, FeatureLayer, Graphic, SimpleRenderer) => {
            const symbol = {
                type: "web-style",
                styleName: "Esri2DPointSymbolsStyle",
                name: "ferry"
            };

            const map = new Map({
                basemap: "satellite"
            });

            const view = new MapView({
                container: "viewDiv",
                map: map,
                zoom: 5,
                center: [-101.94981250000075, 41.20977753557709],
            });

            const graphic = new Graphic({
                geometry: {
                    type: "point", // autocasts as new Point()
                    x: -101.94981250000075,
                    y: 41.20977753557709
                },
                attributes: {
                    objectIdField: 1
                }
            });

            let rotation = 0;

            const rendererVisualVariables = () => [
                {
                    type: "rotation",
                    valueExpression: `${rotation}`
                }
            ];

            const featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
                source: [graphic],
                objectIdField: "ObjectID",
                renderer: new SimpleRenderer({
                    symbol,
                    visualVariables: rendererVisualVariables()
                })
            });

            map.add(featureLayer);

            document.getElementById("rotatePlus45Button").addEventListener("click", () => {
                rotation += 45;
                document.getElementById("rotation").innerHTML = rotation % 360;
                featureLayer.renderer = new SimpleRenderer({
                    symbol,
                    visualVariables: rendererVisualVariables()
                })
            });

            document.getElementById("rotation").innerHTML = rotation % 360;
            
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        Rotation: <span id="rotation"></span>
        <button id="rotatePlus45Button">Rotate +45</button>
    </div>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

In the example, I just use `SimpleRenderer`, to encapsulate the symbol, and then I play with the rotation visual variable property.